# How to create the figure in MatLab?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I got that I should use function `slice` or is it not so? Simply, I don't get how is `V` used if I have function for z?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think there is a built-in function to draw such a plot, and the `slice` function is definitely not for that. However, you can achieve the desired result by drawing several separate patches using [`patch`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/patch.html):

> plots one or more filled polygonal regions using the elements of X and
> Y as the coordinates for each vertex. patch connects the vertices in
> the order that you specify them. To create one polygon, specify X and
> Y as vectors. **To create multiple polygons, specify X and Y (*and Z*) as matrices
> where each column corresponds to a polygon.**

```
nS = 19; % number of slices
ygv = linspace(-2, 2, nS); % position of slices on Y axis
xgv = linspace(-2, 2, 100); % position of points on each curve
[X, Y] = meshgrid(xgv, ygv);
Z = X.^2+Y.^2;
% adding two points with z=0 at both ends of each curve
X = [X(:, 1), X, X(:, end)];
Y = [Y(:, 1), Y, Y(:, end)];
Z = [zeros(nS, 1), Z, zeros(nS, 1)];
patch('Xdata', X', 'Ydata', Y', 'Zdata', Z', 'facecolor', [1 1 1]*0.9);
xlabel('x'), ylabel('y'), zlabel('z')
title('z=x^2+y^2')
grid on
view(3)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks , but there is possible variant is the function waterfall().